# How to find if the Installatoion was per user or per machine installation

Tags: installscript, installshield-2011

I have installed my software on the system in per machine (ALL USER) installation mode.
During the maintenance Install, I want to know whether the software was Installed per user or per machine? How can I do that?
Is there any installscript function or property which can tell me if previous installation was per user or per machine installation?